# Is the function $x|x| + \mathrm{i} y|y|$ analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis

I read in complex analysis that an analytic function is infinitely often differentiable. But the function $x|x| + \mathrm{i} y|y|$ is not even twice differentiable at the origin rather once differentiable. Does it satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann Equation?

Answer (score 1):

On the quadrant $x$, $y>0$ we have
$$f(x+iy)=x^2+iy^2=u+iv.$$
But
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=2x\ne2y=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}.$$

Comment: While checking, whether a function is analytic or not, we check whether it satisfy cauchy riemann condition or not. Now if it satisfies cauchy riemann condition, then can we say that the a function is entire function? what if the C R condition is satisfied somewhere , i mean in some perticular region , and blows up outside that!, is it like now I will say that it's not analytics in that region?... like here CR is satisfied at origin

Answer (score 1):

The function is real differentiable, so we can check the Cauchy-Riemann conditions. Let $u(x,y) = x\vert x\vert$, $v(x,y) = y\vert y\vert$. Then $u_x = 2\vert x \vert$, $v_y=2\vert y\vert$, and so $u_x\neq v_y$, and so $u+vi$ does not satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann conditions.

Comment: The Cauchy-Riemann equations are valid in the origin, furthermore in the set $\lbrace z\in\mathbb{C}\colon |\mathrm{Re}(z)|=|\mathrm{Im}(z)|\rbrace$

Comment: While checking, whether a function is analytic or not, we check whether it satisfy cauchy riemann condition or not. Now if it satisfies cauchy riemann condition, then can we say that the a function is entire function? what if the C R  condition is satisfied somewhere , i mean in some perticular region , and blows up outside that!, is it like now I will say that it's not analytics in that region?... like here CR is satisfied at origin.